# ! operator in Javascript - use cases

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting to learn Javascript, and am using this reference: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/javascript-for-meteor/

There's an interesting commentary that I can't get my head around. I quote  below.

---

An interesting consequence of the ! operator is that it always returns a boolean value, even if what comes after is not a boolean:

```
a = 12;
!a; // false
```

This means that if you want to convert a variable to boolean you can just use the ! operator twice (once to force the variable to boolean, a second time to revert the value back):

```
a = 12;
!!a; // true
Or:

a = 0;
!!a; // false
```

Can anyone help me makes sense of the wording?

Is it simply trying to say that any integer other than 0 gets assigned a Boolean value of True, and that you can return a Boolean value of True/False by using "!" and "!!" respectively?

Comment: it's pretty self explanatory ... ! always returns a boolean ... whether it returns true of false depends on the  operand ... anything "falsey" will result in `true`, anything truthy will result in `false` .... !! will mean anything truthy will result in `true` and anything falsey will result in `false`

Comment: Hm, I get that, but seems like something more is going on here...  "This means that if you want to convert a variable to boolean you can just use the ! operator twice (once to force the variable to boolean, a second time to revert the value back)". Variables get converted to boolean values?

Comment: not variables, values ... `var a = 0; !a;` does NOT change a, it's still `0` ... `!a` is true (in this case, this true value isn't used at all though) - or in other words `var a = 0; if (!a) { this is done because !a is true }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `!!something` is a way to convert `something` into a boolean (essentially finding out whether `something` is truthy). 0 and `NaN` are the only number values that would convert to `false` with the `!!` operator (or `Boolean()` call). All other numbers will be `true`.

Similarly, `+something` is a way to convert `something` into a number.

I usually prefer the more explicit approach: `Boolean(something)` and `Number(something)`.

Comment: `+something is a way to convert something into a number` - or NaN ... which is a number that isn't a Number :p

Comment: NaN, ironically, is a number (a well standardized definition). That's not unique to JS, by the way, even though it's often cited as one of JS's "wat"s.

Comment: yeah, I worded that wrong - NaN means "not a number" but it is a Number

Comment: Okay thanks. So essentially !!a is used to get the boolean value of a. Makes sense now.

Comment: @runawaykid be carefull, `!''` is true but `!'abc'` is false

Comment: @Fireman26 - that's because javascript assigns ' ' the boolean value of False yep?

Comment: @runawaykid - yes